# Which one is faster: array[i] + n vs array[i+1]

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, memory

Suppose I have an array of numbers each one n bigger than the previous.
Given an alement of the array, which method is faster for retrieving the next one?

```
array[i]+n

array[i+1]
```

I know the difference may be infinitesimal but I'm curious theoretically which one is more efficient?

Would it change things if each would be times n (*n) than the previous?

Does the programming language matter? If so, what about javascript?

Comment: Can you provide more context or an example about this statement? "array of numbers each one n bigger than the previous". And programming language matters as well as if the array is static or dynamic. Compiled languages can perform the calculations at compile time rather than run time.

Comment: Just as anecdotal details: in many current CPUs there are instruction formats that access a field in an array with a fixed offset plus a variable offset based on some register and does all of those calculations "for free" (i.e. due to dedicated circuits for this specific calculation, they can be executed at exactly the same speed as a memory access from a fixed address). I can't tell you if any given JavaScript engine on any given system will use that, but that should give you an idea who misleading some "obvious" assumptions about performance like this can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically impossible to answer that in the abstract.

You recognize that the difference (if any) will be very, very small.

At that size of difference *so many* factors can come into play that have a much bigger effect than any fundamental difference.

Prime example: if `array[i]` is currently in the L1 cache of the CPU executing that code, but `array[i+1]` is not, then the first one will be *way* faster, but if it's the other way around then the second one will be faster.

And that doesn't even take into account how compiler/runtime optimizations affect things.

If, for example, the compiler already optimized away a boundary check earlier because it knows that `array` has at least `i` elements, then the second one could force a boundary check, which would slow it down, but reasoning about that in the abstract is basically impossible.

Having said that: memory speed is not growing as quickly as CPU speed. This means that simple calculations will usually be much quicker to re-execute every time than to put into some lookup table. In fact, having a big lookup table can slow down *unrelated* code, since it will require a lot of cache lines and remove other data from the cache that will then have to be fetched from the (relatively slow) RAM chips again.

**tl;dr** The two will be virtually indistinguishable in performance. Any actual, measurable difference will depend heavily on the context they are used in. Measure the performance of *code that does actual relevant work* and act on that.